# Application Lifecycle Management for Web Applications (TFS)

Tags: web, tfs, application-lifecycle, alm

We are working on a web application (Javascript + php). We want to start using Team Foundation Server in order to apply application lifecycle management. but we don't know where to start! any good guide or tutorials?

Comment: Why would ALM be different for a web application?

Comment: I have no experience in this field but want to know if ALM would benefit me by any chance?

Comment: ALM is of no value to anyone using PHP. Since you use PHP, you have no need for source control, or work item tracking, test management, or reporting on the progress of your work. ALM was developed for real applications, not for web applications. After all, web applications have no value in the modern world.

Comment: even if I use Javascript as main language? PHP is a server side language only

Comment: Nobody uses scripting languages anymore. And even if they did, why would you use source control with .js files? Why would you track requirements, or testing? And, does anyone care if you finish your projects?

Comment: John, I'm not sure if you are being sarcastic or not, but I've seen several companies implement strong ALM practices for applications that use scripting languages, especially on the web.  ALM is not just about compiling code!

Comment: Yes, I was being facetious. I even forgot about this because I was waiting for someone to @john me.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you are investigating TFS to be used as an ALM tool in your company, you probably want to take a look at the [free preview of the service that is available in the cloud](http://tfs.visualstudio.com/).  That will allow you to see if this tool will get you what you need.  There a lots of tools out there, but first you need to figure out what your problem is and what you are trying to solve.  TFS may not be the solution you need, but it is a solution for certain teams.

You'll probably likely be using TFS as an ALM tool for the following:

1. **Source Control.**  Ensure you have version history on your changes.  Note: You can now tap into GIT as your repository, if you don't want to use the TFS source control.
2. **Continuous Integration.**  You can make your build configurations deploy your files out to your environments, and run unit tests if necessary.
3. **Bug Tracking.**  Use the built-in work items to track all your bugs.
4. **Requirements Tracking.** Use Scrum or Kanban for your project to take advantage of the boards that are available with the service.  Work items like 'Stories' or 'Product Backlog Items' will let you track the work your team is delivering.
5. **Burndown.**  The built-in reports should help you report to your management on progress, though you'll have to see if the TFS ones meet your needs.
6. **Test Cases.** Your QA team can write their test cases in TFS to document how to test the requirements.  If you have the correct license, you can also tap in Microsoft Test Manager for your QA team to execute and plan their tests.

I would strongly advise doing some research into what ALM means, what it is used for, and why you should be doing it before deciding on a tool.   The tool won't fix the problem, it just supports you in whatever you are doing to fix your problem.

Comment: Sorry you didn't get my joke. ALM is just as important for web applications as any other kind.